# What is the conjugate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

What is the conjugate?
$\sqrt x +2 \sqrt b$
I'm not sure how to find the conjugate of any term. Help, please?

Comment: It's (most likely) $\sqrt x\color{red}-2\sqrt b$.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_(algebra)

Answer (score 2):

You have a number $\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{b}$ and you're asking for the conjugate.

Most times this refers to the [complex conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate), which involves replacing the imaginary part of the complex number with its negative.

Your number is a purely real number, so its complex conjugate is itself.

However, you may be wanting to rationalize a denominator of a fraction, in which case perhaps what you're looking for is the same expression with the second term having opposite sign, also called the [binomial conjugate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_%28algebra%29), so you can multiply top and bottom by it to get rid of the square roots in the bottom?

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x} + 2 \sqrt{b}} \times \frac{\sqrt{x} - 2 \sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{x} - 2 \sqrt{b}}= \frac{\sqrt{x} + 2 \sqrt{b}}{x + 4b}.$$

In this case, the conjugate involves switching the sign of the second term:  $\sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{b}$.

(Note that the value of the conjugate depends on how it's written.  If it were written $2\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{x}$, the conjugate of this expression would be $2\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{x}$.)

Comment: What if i just needed the conjugate of the equation? Somebody said that you just switch the signs... Is that true?

Comment: That's likely what you need, yes.  That's what I did in the example above.  You can rationalize the denominator using the difference of squares by multiplying the denominator by its conjugate.

Comment: Added information to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the conjugate we switch the sign in between the two terms $\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{b}$. We do this to create a difference of squares. The **difference of squares** can be seen in this example: $$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$$ Notice how we don't have a middle term. This is intentional and the result of using the **difference of squares**.

$$=\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x} + 2 \sqrt{b}}\right)\cdot\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{x} - 2 \sqrt{b}}\right) $$

$$=\dfrac{1\left(\sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{b}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x}+2\sqrt{b}\right)\left(\sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{b}\right)}$$

$$=\boxed{\dfrac{\sqrt{x}-2\sqrt{b}}{x-4b}}$$